# Циклический сдвиг. Python

Tags: python, массивы, математика, numpy, jupyter-notebook

```
import random
import math
import numpy as np

A=np.array([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]])
B=np.array([[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]])
print(A)
L=2 #Количество строк
H=4 #Количество столбцов



for x in range(L):
    for y in range(H):
        if (y+1)==H:
            y=0

        B[x][y]=A[x][y+1]

print(B)
```

Хочу реализовать циклический сдвиг влево, для начала выбрал этот сдвиг равным 1. Но у меня не заполняется последний столбец. Помогите исправить

И еще скажите, как реализовать код, если сдвиг больше количества строк/столбцов

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь [numpy.roll()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.roll.html):

```
In [61]: A
Out[61]:
array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
       [5, 6, 7, 8]])

In [62]: B = np.roll(A, -1, axis=1)

In [63]: B
Out[63]:
array([[2, 3, 4, 1],
       [6, 7, 8, 5]])
```

---

PS если вы используете `Numpy`, то постарайтесь приучить себя использовать циклы только в безвыходных ситуациях.

Вот еще одно решение "в лоб" без использования циклов:

```
n = 1
B = np.column_stack((A[:, n:], A[:, :n]))
```

результат:

```
In [116]: B
Out[116]:
array([[2, 3, 4, 1],
       [6, 7, 8, 5]])
```

---

сравним скорость обработки для матрицы размерностью 1.000 x 1.000:

```
In [127]: a = np.random.randint(10**6, size=(1000, 1000))

In [128]: a.shape
Out[128]: (1000, 1000)

In [129]: b = np.zeros((1000, 1000))

In [130]: %%timeit
     ...: for x in range(a.shape[0]):
     ...:     for y in range(a.shape[1]):
     ...:         k = (y+1)%H
     ...:         b[x][y]=a[x][k]
     ...:
935 ms ± 13.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [135]: %%timeit
     ...: b = np.column_stack((a[:, n:], a[:, :n]))
     ...:
     ...:
2.52 ms ± 41 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [136]: %%timeit
     ...: b = np.roll(a, -n, axis=1)
     ...:
     ...:
2.49 ms ± 3.59 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [137]: 935 / 2.52
Out[137]: 371.031746031746

In [138]: 935 / 2.49
Out[138]: 375.50200803212846
```

Comment: То есть через вложенный цикл это нельзя реализовать?

Comment: @steam-ilka, конечно можно, но это будет гораздо "кривее" и медленнее... ) Или у вас чисто академический интерес?

Comment: принял) Но мне для общего понимания, что я неправильно сделал или что я не добавил, дабы мой цикл работал? Можете подсказать?

Comment: да, академический )

Answer (score 1):

Это ответ на ваш "академический" вопрос. Индекс, откуда брать надо не y+1, а чуть сложнее

```
for x in range(L):
    for y in range(H):
        k = (y+1)%H
        B[x][y]=A[x][k]
```

*если сдвиг больше количества строк/столбцов*

```
L = L % A.shape[0]
H = H % A.shape[1]
```